# #pragma pack(push, 8) does not work as expected

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-alignment, pragma

I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and Windows 7 x64. I write in C++.

I have one structure, and I need proper access to it's fields both in x86 and x64 applications. That's why I added `#pragma pack(push, 8)`. Here is the structure:

```
#pragma pack(push, 8)
typedef struct 
{
    BOOL    Inst;
    HANDLE  hEvent;
    HANDLE  hModuleMemory;
    DWORD   dwModuleSize;
    HANDLE  hFileMemory;
    DWORD   dwFileSize;
}
INIT_DATA, *LPINIT_DATA;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

But this does not work as expected; alignment is 4 bytes in x86. For example, this code:

```
DWORD dwOffset = offsetof(INIT_DATA, hEvent);
DWORD dwSize   = sizeof(INIT_DATA);

DebugPrint(DEBUG_INFO, "dwOffset = %d; dwSize = %d\n", dwOffset, dwSize);
```

outputs this:

```
[INFO] <main.cpp:572 TID:51536 ERR:0> WinMain(): dwOffset = 4; dwSize = 24
```

If I change packing to `#pragma pack(push, 4)` output is still the same!

How can I get 8-byte alignment to work?

Comment: If you didn't insist on putting a BOOL (32 bits) in front of a HANDLE (32 or 64 bits), the compiler wouldn't have to add padding. Order the elements by decreasing size, like HANDLEs, DWORDs, BOOL. That said, check system headers for examples of packing with MSVC.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I ordered elements by decrasing size and offset of second `HANDLE` element is still 4. Is there a way to make each field offset aligned to 8?

Comment: Use pragma pack show option to display the actual settings.

Comment: @ZDF it shows `value of pragma pack(show) == 8`.

Comment: `#pragma pack` can only make a structure tighter, never sparser. E.g. if you have `struct S { char a, b;}` the two members will be at offsets 0 and 1 regardless of packing. You could probably get to the desired outcome with something like `union {HANDLE hEvent; LONGLONG dummy;};` members.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I need one structure definition which could be included from both x86 and x64 projects. HANDLE is 4 bytes on x86 and 8 bytes on x64. Is there a MSVC way to do it? Of course I can use `#ifdef _X86` and add dummy padding.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can tell the compile to align an object's address to a multiple of a number of bytes. I think that's actually what you want.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion and found it lacking, then? In what way did it fail to satisfy your requirements? Seems to [work for me](http://rextester.com/WOG62385)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik of course it works; but I wonder if there is an another (maybe MSVC-specific) way like `#pragma pack` to make each field aligned to 8.

Comment: Has my code not made each field aligned to 8? I fail to grasp the nature of the problem. What difficulty still remains to be resolved?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik your code works perfectly, and I can use it. I wonder about if there is a built-in MSVC solution, something like `forcealign(8)` to do that. If no, I can use dummy paddings.

Comment: Ah. You are probably looking for `__declspec(align(8))`, like [this](http://rextester.com/SQTHV80758)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thank you, it works perfectly now :)